How can I get the parent of a Gitlab pipeline with GraphQL without using iid?
I have a Gitlab pipeline ID, but this pipeline has been triggered by another one, and I need to access to the properties of this parent pipeline. For this, I only have the pipeline id, which should be enough to get what I want, but GraphQL returns "null" unless I use pipeline's iid.
I can get this iid from Gitlab API, but it's pretty suspicious to have to do an extra call for that.
First, I tried to get the parent pipeline by accessing the child pipeline by id using this request :
{
  project(fullPath: "project/project") {
    id
    pipeline(id: "gid://gitlab/Ci::Pipeline/702555") {
      id
      upstream {
        id
        project {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But I got a "null" pipeline from GraphQL
{
  "data": {
    "project": {
      "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/845",
      "pipeline": null
    }
  }
}

But that's strange, because when I call Gitlab API to read my pipeline, I get this response :
{
    "id": 702555,
    "iid": 52659,
    "project_id": 845,
    [...]
}

And if I call GraphQL using this iid, I have the response I am waiting for... Here is the query :
{
  project(fullPath: "project/project") {
    id
    pipeline(iid: 52659) {
      id
      upstream {
        id
        project {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And the response :
{
  "data": {
    "project": {
      "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/845",
      "pipeline": {
        "id": "gid://gitlab/Ci::Pipeline/702555",
        "upstream": {
          "id": "gid://gitlab/Ci::Pipeline/702540",
          "project": {
            "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/845"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Even GraphQL is telling me that the pipeline I'm looking for have "gid://gitlab/Ci::Pipeline/702555" as id... It's also not linked to how I refer to the pipeline id, because if I get pipelines list :
{
  project(fullPath: "project/project") {
    id
    pipelines {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And call with one of the id I got from GraphQL, I get a pipeline ; is this list incomplete and GraphQL is trying to get my pipeline from this incomplete list ?
If there's a way to retrieve the parent pipeline from Gitlab API I'm in too, but I didn't find anything about that (except "use GraphQL").
Thank you for your assistance.
